# Same Galois group for two polynomials

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ be two polynomials such that $f|g$ over some finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$. If $K_f, K_g$ are the number fields defined by these polynomials, i.e., $K = \mathbb{Q}[\theta]$ for some algebraic integer $\theta$ and minimal polynomial $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, then is it true that $Aut(K_f) = Aut(K_g)$, i.e., they have the same Galois group ?

Thanks

Comment: The minimal poynomial of an algebraic number is irreducible. If $f$ an $g$ are minimal polynomials of numbers and $f$ divides $g$, then $f$ and $g$ are in factt equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is false with trivial counterexamples. Let $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x^2+1$. Then clearly your conditions are satisfied but $K_f=\mathbb{Q}$ and $K_g=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ which have different automorphism groups ($\{e\}$ and $C_2$ respectively).

If you add the extra requirement that $deg(f),deg(g)>1$ then the theorem becomes true, but vacuously so because you require $g$ be irreducible (since it's the minimal polynomial of a number field) but also that $f|g$ which means that $f$ must be of degree $1$. Thus nothing satisfies the hypotheses so the statement is vacuously true.